How do I remove list() from a Corpus?
I have three text files. After preprocessing them using Corpus and the tm package, the resulting text includes the phrases "list(language = "portuguese")" and "list()".
When I tokenize the text or create a document-term matrix (DTM), the final result always includes words from these phrases and the name of each file, including ".txt".
I already tried using the unlist() function without success.
Here is my code:
docs <- Corpus(DirSource("FILE PATH"), readerControl = list(language = "portuguese")) 

toSpace <- content_transformer(function(x, pattern) { return (gsub(pattern, " ", x))})

docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "-")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, ":")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, "'")
docs <- tm_map(docs, toSpace, " -")

removeSpecialChars <- function(x) gsub('[[:punct:]]',"",x)
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeSpecialChars)

docs %<>%
    tm_map(removePunctuation) %>%
    tm_map(content_transformer(tolower)) %>%
    tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
    tm_map(removeWords, stopwords("portuguese")) %>%
    tm_map(stripWhitespace)
class(docs)

docs %<>%
    tm_map(content_transformer(gsub), pattern = "WORD1", replacement = " WORD2 ") %>%
    tm_map(content_transformer(gsub), pattern = "WORD 3 WORD4", replacement = " WORD5 ")

docs <- tm_map(docs, stripWhitespace)
docs <- ptstem(as.character(docs), algorithm = "rslp")


The documentation for Corpus suggests that languages should be ideally be specified using ISO 639-1.  So does language = "pt"improve matters?

I'm not sure of its importance, but unfortunately, removing it doesn't solve the problem. Instead, the result now includes the words from the phrase "list(language = "en")".
